# Had vs was grammatical part

Tags: grammar, british-english

Can we write I had born instead of I was born? Please explain it. Which one should I write in a sentence. Please explain elaborately.

Comment: Your use of the word "elaborately" is odd and unnatural.  You should remove that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Born is an odd word.  It isn't the regular past participle of "bear" (that is borne) It is nearly always used in the phrase "be born", which is derived from a passive voice expression but should not now be analysed as a passive.

On the other hand "had borne" (sometimes written "had born") would be a past perfect and an active voice.  It would almost never be used.

> I was born in France (correct)

> I had born in France (incorrect)

> My father came to America in 1945. My mother had borne him a child (me!) in France during the war.  (correct but very odd phrasing)